# How to do in SQL: one row from two rows with same value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this in SQL:

[image: SQL table example]

I would like to create simple rows from rows with the same `game_id` value. 
Thus, I would like to have the first two rows in the first row; the third, fourth row as the second row, and so on. My table is huge.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What would your desired output look like? What are you doing with the other two columns?

Comment: I would like to create new columns as well, so for example: the first row should look like: 1 | POR | 76 | LAL | 96. Second row: 2 |  CHI | 108 | MIL | 95.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select game_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then team_id end) as team_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then score end) as score_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then team_id end) as team_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then score end) as score_2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by game_id order by game_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by game_id;
```

I should note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the resulting columns might not be in the same order as the rows you have shown.  If you have an ordering, then you can use that in the `order by`.